# should you ever expose a function to front-end that writes data to database?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase

I have a function embeded in my front-end web code to takes orders from authenticated users. A curious user decides to examine my web code and come to know about this function. So he finds out the location in my database where orders are being stored and also that authenticated users have access to write in that collection. He decides to spam orders collection and fills my database with adult messages. How would i be able to stop that?

```
    orderButton.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        db.collection('orders').add({item: e.target.id, buyer: user.uid})
    })
```

Should i perform a cloud function in backend to check the validity or limit the orders per hour. If that is so why shouldn't i write the order function in backend at first place and then call from front-end?

Firebase charges extra for backend cloud functions so i was wondering any method to save costs and do all the magic in front-end?

Comment: check if the user is authenticated on the server side.

Comment: "*How would i be able to stop that?*' by not exposing valuable functionality in the front-end "*any method to save costs and do all the magic in front-end?*" if the costs you want to save include "don't bother with security" and you're fine with being vulnerable, then go ahead. Otherwise, why would you want to be *less* secure?

Comment: i am noob coder. Don't know much about security and vulnerebilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing directly to a database from a client side is one of the features of Firebase, but it can not be used just for everything. Best appliances of it are, for example, letting user change their own description, or profile picture, or editing own blog posts. Something that can't hurt anyone else. You should write sufficient [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) to eliminate any possible abuse of this feature, for example, you don't let users edit other users' blog posts

Having one `orders` collection where every user (even authenticated) can write should not ever be done. If you let users create orders in `orders` db, there's nothing stopping any user from spamming that db with fake orders, or creating orders from other users' name (by entering any other id in `buyer` field). You can't trust data in that collection

It's not about exposing a function in your client side code that someone can read, but more about having security rules that even allow this kind of operations

To summarize and answer your question, sometimes it's ok to let users write directly to a database under properly designed security rules, but in your scenario this isn't the case. If you want `orders` collection to be trustable, you should manage it from server side

Comment: i know firestore security rules pretty well but don't know much about client side security. I have never made a live app.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add private token to solve it. I think the best way to solve the issue is place the function on the backend side and call it from the frontend.